# How to Run 2 different Scripts Successfully Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I have two different code blocks. One runs against an endpoint, and the other block runs against a different endpoint. If they are run separately, it runs fine. But I need to have them both run successfully right after the other in one file. Can someone help me please?

First block:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"

$url = "https://FIRSTENDPOINT.com/Integration-Server/XXXXXXIntegrations?requestJobDescription={""type"":""file"",""credentials"":{""partnerUserID"":""XXXXX"",""partnerUserSecret"":""XXXXXX""},""onReceive"":{""immediateResponse"":[""returnRandomFileName""]},""inputSettings"":{""type"":""combinedReportData"",""filters"":{""startDate"":""2018-01-01""}},""outputSettings"":{""fileExtension"":""pdf"",""includeFullPageReceiptsPdf"":""False"",""fileBasename"":""ExpenseReimbursementReport""}}"

$template = '<#if addHeader == true>
    Employee Name, Amount, Status, Report Date, Employee Email, Report ID<#lt>
</#if>
    <#list reports as report>
    <#setting date_format="MM/dd/yyyy">
    <#setting locale="en_US">
    <#assign total = report.total/100>
    ${report.submitter.fullName},<#t>
    ${total},<#t>   
    ${report.status},<#t>
    ${report.submitted?date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")},<#t>
    ${report.accountEmail},<#t>
    ${report.reportID}<#lt>
</#list>'

$encode = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($template)

Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Uri $url'&template='$encode -OutVariable temp

$Data=$temp.split(",")
$var= @{}

$i=0
foreach ($item in $Data)
{$var[$i] = "https://XXXXX.com/Integration-Server/XXXXIntegrations?requestJobDescription={""type"":""download"",""credentials"":{""partnerUserID"":""XXXXX"",""partnerUserSecret"":""XXXXXX""},""fileName"":"+$item+"}"
$output = "C:\files\$item"
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Uri $var[$i] -Outfile $output
$i++
```

Second block:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
$obj = New-Object psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "username" -Value "XXXXX"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "password" -Value "XXXXX"
$body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $obj

$login="https://2ndENDPOINT.com/v4/login?fbsite=https://XXXXX.com/"


Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Body $body -Uri $login -OutVariable AUTHtemp

$filepath="C:\files\"
$data_files = Get-ChildItem $Folder_file_path

$filesss=$data_files | Write-Output

$Data2= $filesss -split "`n"
$var2= @{}

$i2=0
foreach ($item2 in $Data2)
{


$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept", 'application/pdf')

$fileName="C:\files\$item2"
$fileContent = get-content -Raw $fileName
$fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($fileContent)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)


$data = ConvertTo-Json @{

encrypted="false";
allowSaveBinaryData="true";
binaryData="$fileContentEncoded"
divider="Expense Report";
extension="pdf";
name="$fileContentEncoded";
relProjectId="31";
fileID="597"
}

$var2[$i2]="https://XXXXXX.com/v4/documents/597?guid=$AUTHtemp&fbsite=https://XXXXXX.com/"

Invoke-RestMethod -headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Method PUT -body $data -Uri $var2[$i2]}

$i2++
```

**EDIT:**

When I try to run them in the same file, either just as one block or as function, it throws a ton of errors. I had to stop it after the 12th error because it just kept creating empty files and throwing errors each time:

```
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\files\Box Sync' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\USER\Documents\ExpenseReimbursement_Powershell\Expense_GetReports.ps1:65 char:16
+ $fileContent = get-content -Raw $fileName
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\files\Box Sync:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Exception calling "GetBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: chars"
At C:\Users\USER\Documents\ExpenseReimbursement_Powershell\Expense_GetReports.ps1:66 char:1
+ $fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($fileCon ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "ToBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inArray"
At C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\ExpenseReimbursement_Powershell\Expense_GetReports.ps1:67 char:1
+ $fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBy ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

Comment: If they do not run successfully, what does happen? Error messages?

Comment: Hi Lit, Please see above edit. Thank you.

Comment: It's only suppose to get 2 pdf's from file location C:\files but instead looks for all these other files. But when I run them separatetly, it runs fine.

Comment: Please disregard the comments and edits. Briantist provided the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to put the entire second block of code after the first block, in the same file.

At that point the program would flow naturally from the first to the second.

But since each block seems to represent a specific operation, this might be a good opportunity to put each one in a function to encapsulate it.

This also lets you turn your code into a sort of "template" in that you can pass in the values that might change as parameters, and then you get a nice re-usable set of operations that you call as one. I won't cover that just yet but it's something to think about.

I'm not entirely sure what your first block is supposed to do (as a high-level operation) but I'm going to guess and describe it as "post integration results", so I'll call this function `Register-IntegrationResult` (this follows PowerShell `Verb-Noun` naming convention, using an approved verb, and a singular noun, but you could name the function just about anything you want):

```
function Register-IntegrationResult {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"

    $url = "https://FIRSTENDPOINT.com/Integration-Server/XXXXXXIntegrations?requestJobDescription={""type"":""file"",""credentials"":{""partnerUserID"":""XXXXX"",""partnerUserSecret"":""XXXXXX""},""onReceive"":{""immediateResponse"":[""returnRandomFileName""]},""inputSettings"":{""type"":""combinedReportData"",""filters"":{""startDate"":""2018-01-01""}},""outputSettings"":{""fileExtension"":""pdf"",""includeFullPageReceiptsPdf"":""False"",""fileBasename"":""ExpenseReimbursementReport""}}"

    $template = '<#if addHeader == true>
        Employee Name, Amount, Status, Report Date, Employee Email, Report ID<#lt>
    </#if>
        <#list reports as report>
        <#setting date_format="MM/dd/yyyy">
        <#setting locale="en_US">
        <#assign total = report.total/100>
        ${report.submitter.fullName},<#t>
        ${total},<#t>   
        ${report.status},<#t>
        ${report.submitted?date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")},<#t>
        ${report.accountEmail},<#t>
        ${report.reportID}<#lt>
    </#list>'

    $encode = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($template)

    Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Uri $url'&template='$encode -OutVariable temp

    $Data=$temp.split(",")
    $var= @{}

    $i=0
    foreach ($item in $Data)
    {
        $var[$i] = "https://XXXXX.com/Integration-Server/XXXXIntegrations?requestJobDescription={""type"":""download"",""credentials"":{""partnerUserID"":""XXXXX"",""partnerUserSecret"":""XXXXXX""},""fileName"":"+$item+"}"
        $output = "C:\files\$item"
        Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Uri $var[$i] -Outfile $output
        $i++
    }
}
```

Similar with the second block in that I don't know what it's doing, but I'll guess it's uploading some kind of report, so I'll call it `Send-ImportantReport`:

```
function Send-ImportantReport {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "username" -Value "XXXXX"
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "password" -Value "XXXXX"
    $body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $obj

    $login="https://2ndENDPOINT.com/v4/login?fbsite=https://XXXXX.com/"


    Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Post -Body $body -Uri $login -OutVariable AUTHtemp

    $filepath="C:\files\"
    $data_files = Get-ChildItem $Folder_file_path

    $filesss=$data_files | Write-Output

    $Data2= $filesss -split "`n"
    $var2= @{}

    $i2=0
    foreach ($item2 in $Data2)
    {


        $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        $headers.Add("Accept", 'application/pdf')

        $fileName="C:\files\$item2"
        $fileContent = get-content -Raw $fileName
        $fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($fileContent)
        $fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)


        $data = ConvertTo-Json @{
            encrypted="false";
            allowSaveBinaryData="true";
            binaryData="$fileContentEncoded"
            divider="Expense Report";
            extension="pdf";
            name="$fileContentEncoded";
            relProjectId="31";
            fileID="597"
        }
    }
}
```

So what's the point of this? Now when you want to call one after the other, your code looks like this:

```
Register-IntegrationResult
Send-ImportantReport
```

If you needed to do them more than once, you just call by name.

As a future change you might want to add parameters, that way parts that can change like the credentials, URL, or local file paths can be passed in. Then your calls might look something like this:

```
Register-IntegrationResult -JobID 1234
Send-ImportantReport -Path C:\Reports
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I did try to run it as a function in one file and got errors. If I run the script separately one file after the other, then it "blows" up on me. Please see edit above.

Comment: Actually, this answers my question. I realized I had a typo in one of the functions that was throwing everything off. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @LilithMae great, glad you got it resolved! I'm not sure what editor you're using at the moment, but PowerShell ISE comes with Windows and is decent for writing PowerShell, but more recently the free and open source [Visual Studio Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-6) has become much more popular, and is even Microsoft's recommendation. It has great features and its code formatting will make it easier to write in a style that helps follow the code, in terms of bracket / brace placement and such. Hope that helps!